# Problemas ao salvar com selectOneMenu.

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando salvar um registro de Atividades com informação de Favorecido.

Não consigo salvar de nenhuma maneira.  Vou colocar o código e por favor se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço.

<

```html
package br.com.sentinel.Bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import org.omnifaces.util.Messages;
import br.com.sentinela.DAO.ReceitaDespesaDAO;
import br.com.sentinela.Domain.ReceitaDespesa;
import br.com.sentinela.DAO.FavorecidoDAO;
import br.com.sentinela.Domain.Favorecido;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped


public class ReceitaDespesaBean implements Serializable{
 
 private ReceitaDespesa rd;
 
 public List<Favorecido> getFavorecidos() {
  return favorecidos;
 }
 public void setFavorecidos(List<Favorecido> favorecidos) {
  this.favorecidos = favorecidos;
 }

 private List<ReceitaDespesa> rds;
 private List<Favorecido> favorecidos;
 public ReceitaDespesa getRd() {
  return rd;
 }
 public void setRd(ReceitaDespesa rd) {
  this.rd = rd;
 }
 public List<ReceitaDespesa> getRds() {
  return rds;
 }
 public void setRds(List<ReceitaDespesa> rds) {
  this.rds = rds;
 }
 public List<Favorecido> getFavorecido() {
  return favorecidos;
 }
 public void setFavorecido(List<Favorecido> favorecidos) {
  this.favorecidos = favorecidos;
 }
 
 @PostConstruct
 public void listar() {
  try {
   ReceitaDespesaDAO rdDAO = new ReceitaDespesaDAO();
   rds = rdDAO.listar();
  } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
   Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar listar as RDs.");
   erro.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public void novo() {
  try {
   rd = new ReceitaDespesa();

   ReceitaDespesaDAO rdDAO = new ReceitaDespesaDAO();
   rds = rdDAO.listar();
   
   FavorecidoDAO favorecidoDAO = new FavorecidoDAO();
   favorecidos = favorecidoDAO.listar();
      
  } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
   Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao gerar uma as RDs");
   erro.printStackTrace();
  }
 }


 public void salvar() {
   try {
    ReceitaDespesaDAO rdDAO = new ReceitaDespesaDAO();
    rdDAO.merge(rd);

   rd = new ReceitaDespesa();

   FavorecidoDAO favorecidoDAO = new FavorecidoDAO();
   favorecidos = favorecidoDAO.listar();   

   Messages.addGlobalInfo("Despesas salva com sucesso");
  } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
   Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar uma atividade");
   erro.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public void excluir(ActionEvent evento) {
  try {
   rd = (ReceitaDespesa) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("rdSelecionada");

   ReceitaDespesaDAO rdDAO = new ReceitaDespesaDAO();
   rdDAO.excluir(rd);

   rds = rdDAO.listar();

   Messages.addGlobalInfo("RD removido com sucesso");
  } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
   Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar remover uma RD");
   erro.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public void editar(ActionEvent evento){
  try {
   rd = (ReceitaDespesa) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("rdSelecionada");

   FavorecidoDAO favorecidoDAO = new FavorecidoDAO();
   favorecidos = favorecidoDAO.listar();
      
   
  } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
   Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar selecionar uma RD");
   erro.printStackTrace();
  } 
 }

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      template="/templates/template.xhtml">
<h:head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Atividades - receitas e despesas</title>
</h:head>
<ui:define name="conteudo">
<h:body >
<!-- <p:growl id="mensagem"/> -->
 <h:form id="formListagem"> 
  <p:panel header="Atividades" >
   <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado."
    paginator="true"
    value="#{receitaDespesaBean.rds}" var="rd" id="tabela"
    rows="6"  rowsPerPageTemplate="6,12"
    >
    <f:facet name="header">
     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();"
     actionListener="#{receitaDespesaBean.novo()}"
     update=":formCadastro:pnCadastro" />
     
     <p:button icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w" outcome="/paginas/principal.xhtml" >
     </p:button>
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Descrição" sortBy="#{rd.descricao}" filterBy="#{rd.descricao}">
     <h:outputText value="#{rd.descricao}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Tipo" sortBy="#{rd.RD}" filterBy="#{rd.RD}">
     <h:outputText value="#{rd.RD}" />
    </p:column>
    

    <p:column headerText="Opções">
    
     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
       actionListener="#{receitaDespesaBean.excluir}"
       update=":mensagem :formCadastro:pnCadastro :formListagem:tabela">
       <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir o estado?"
       icon="ui-icon-alert" />
       <f:attribute name="rdSelecionado" value="#{rd}" />
     </p:commandButton>
     
     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil"
      actionListener="#{receitaDespesaBean.editar}"
      update=":mensagem :formCadastro:pnCadastro :formListagem:tabela"
      oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();">
      <f:attribute name="rdSelecionado" value="#{rd}" />
     </p:commandButton>
     
     
     
     
    </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   
   <p:confirmDialog global="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button"
     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button"
     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
   </p:confirmDialog>
   
  </p:panel>
 </h:form>

 <p:dialog header="Atividades - Cadastro" widgetVar="dialogo"
  draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="false" closable="false">
  <h:form id="formCadastro">
   <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="pnCadastro">
    <p:outputLabel value="Descrição:" />
    <p:inputText maxlength="50" size="30" value="#{receitaDespesaBean.rd.descricao}"
     required="true" requiredMessage="O campo 'Descrição' é obrigatório"/>
    
    <p:outputLabel value="Atividade:" />
    <p:selectOneRadio value="#{receitaDespesaBean.rd.RD}">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="R" itemLabel="Receita" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="D" itemLabel="Despesa" />
     
    </p:selectOneRadio>
    
    
    
    <p:outputLabel value="Favorecido:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu filter="true" value="#{receitaDespesaBean.rd.favorecido}"
                     converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
    >
    
    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"
      itemLabel="Selecione um favorecido" />    
    <f:selectItems value="#{receitaDespesaBean.favorecidos}" var="favorecido"
                 itemValue="#{favorecido}" itemLabel="#{favorecido.descricao}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    
  
    
   </h:panelGrid>

   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:commandButton value="Salvar"  actionListener="#{favorecidoBean.salvar()}"
     update=":mensagem :formCadastro:pnCadastro :formListagem:tabela"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Fechar" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();" />
   </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
 </p:dialog>
 
</h:body>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Alguem pode me dar uma força?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

você precisa popular o rd no método salvar antes de enviar para o DAO.